# Difference between 光る, 輝く, and 光り輝く?

Tags: word-choice, nuances

What is the difference between 光る{ひかる}, 輝く{かがやく}, and 光り{ひかり}輝く{かがやく}? According to my dictionary, they all mean "to shine" or "to be bright", but I'm sure they aren't always interchangeable. Looking at example sentences, it seems that the sun, moon, a star, and a diamond can both 光る and 輝く, but eyes mostly 輝く. I can't figure out anything based on that, though, and I'm not even sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that 光る is something that emits/reflects light. The sun. A star. A flashlight. An LED.

輝く is to shimmer/sparkle. The sun reflecting off a lake's waves does 輝く. A diamond reflecting light does this.

As for 光り輝く, it's the same thing as 輝く.

And as someone else here said, if you just want to compare words to get a nuanced meaning of the word, a google image search is always a great thing to use.

Comment: ハゲ頭 doesn't emit light but 光る.

Comment: Apologies - I thought "items that emit light" was a superset of "items that reflect light." I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Is there anything that can 輝く but can't 光る?

Answer (score 2):

輝く is more of a sparkle/shine, instead of just a plain shine.  Shimmer maybe? And 光る as to give off light.   This might be the only time in the history of the community that a Google Image Search of [輝く](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E8%BC%9D%E3%81%8F&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=FW8pVdzBC8K1oQTxpoHACQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1216&bih=977) versus [光る](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%85%89%E3%82%8B&hl=en&biw=1216&bih=977&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tm8pVeTbG5D1oASb_IGYDg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)　will explain this better than a dictionary answer.

Comment: @Blavius to give off light sparklingly